# PREMATURE END OF FILE - XWPFDocument to PDFConverter

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word, apache-poi, pdf-conversion

Instead of appending the content  of a document to CTBody Class, I am transfering all the data from a word document to an empty document using XWPFDocument class but 
I am getting an error as below. the error is pointed on XWPFDocument doc when I convert it to pdf

fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Premature end of file.

```
        FileInputStream fis   = new FileInputStream("1.docx");
        FileInputStream fis1  = new FileInputStream("2.docx");

        XWPFDocument xdoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
        XWPFDocument xdoc1 = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis1));

        CTBody ct = xdoc.getDocument().getBody();
        CTBody ct1 = xdoc1.getDocument().getBody();

        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
        doc.createStyles();

        doc.getDocument().addNewBody().set(ct);
        doc.getDocument().addNewBody().set(ct1);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( new File("test.pdf"));
        PdfOptions opt = PdfOptions.create();
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(doc, out, opt);

        doc.write(out);
        doc.close();
        out.close();
```

this is the stacktrace.

```
  fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Premature end of file.
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:71)
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:39)
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.AbstractXWPFConverter.convert(AbstractXWPFConverter.java:46)
at trafficMan.MainApp.mergeDocument(MainApp.java:513)
at trafficMan.MainApp$2.actionPerformed(MainApp.java:609)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Premature end of file.
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3448)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1272)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1259)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.StylesDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.getStyle(XWPFDocument.java:557)
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.XWPFStylesDocument.<init>(XWPFStylesDocument.java:196)
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.XWPFStylesDocument.<init>(XWPFStylesDocument.java:190)
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.createStylesDocument(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:182)
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.<init>(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:175)
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.<init>(PdfMapper.java:155)
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:56)
... 40 more
 Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file://; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3422)
... 51 more
```

Comment: Even this code does nothing else than simply appending multiple document bodies. But according to `Office Open XML` a `CT_Document` can only have **one** element of type `CT_Body`.

Answer (score 1):

Even this code does nothing else than simply appending multiple document bodies. It first creates a new `XWPFDocument` which contains one `CTBody` already. Then it uses    `XWPFDocument.getDocument()` which gets the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1` of that new `XWPFDocument` and then it adds two new `CTBody` elements to that. After that the `CTDocument1` will have **three** `CTBody` elements.

But according to `Office Open XML` a `CT_Document` can only have **one** element of type `CT_Body`.

The following XML Schema fragment defines the contents of the `CT_Document` element:

```
<complexType name="CT_Document">
 <complexContent>
  <extension base="CT_DocumentBase">
   <sequence>
    <element name="body" type="CT_Body" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   </sequence>
  </extension>
 </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

As you see: `CT_Body` occurs 1 times max.

Merging two `Word` documents is more than simply concatenating the document bodies. All the elements in the bodies needs to be merged in one `CTBody` element. And there are other parts of the single `Word` file systems (themes, styles, font table, comments, numbering, media, ...) which also needs merged. I do not know any free `Java` library except  `OpenOffice` or `LibreOffice` which can do this properly.